# How to place place the custom css in style tags directly on page above the shortcode WPress

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode

Hi i have a plugin "WP Links Page" but when I change the css style via custom css then ALL sites are with the same look. So I need to change each site with css code and got that tip :

You can place the custom css in style tags directly on page above the shortcode.

My question is, HOW and WHERE can I insert css style before the shortcode in Wordpress, so that
each shortcodes have different look of each css style.

Can you help me there ?

Best wishes ...thx in adv.

Tony

I copy the code of to the "text" editor in WP in the Posting part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page-id so that the css will work only on that page
or you can put the shortcodes inside divs/sections with custom ID's